Authorithy URL format when creating database scoped credential in Azure sql
I'd like to create a database scoped credential using an Entra Service Principal.
We want to use this credential to mount an external table from another Azure SQL database.
Is this functionality supported?
If yes, what is the exact formatting of AuthorityUrl?
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [<CredentialName>] WITH
IDENTITY = '<AppID>@<AuthorityUrl>' 
, SECRET = '<Secret>'
GO

Tried everything but cannot get it to work.
When trying to read from external table, I always get the following error(s):
 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open server "login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token" requested by the login.


According to the MS document service principle doesn't support cross-database queries in azure sql database. You can use SQL Server authentication


[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open server "login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token" requested by the login.

According to the  MS document,

elastic queries are only supported when connecting with SQL Server Authentication.

Service principal authentication doesn't support cross-database queries in azure SQL database. That may be the reason to get above error while creating scoped credential. You can use SQL Server authentication as follows:
If you have two sample Azure SQL databases,  db  and  db1. Create a master key and scoped credential in the  db1  database using the code below:
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<Password>';

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL <name> WITH IDENTITY = '<userName>',
SECRET = '<Password>';


